# Importar dados no mysql a partir de um layout

Tags: php, mysql

Estou importando alguns dados na tabela "tb_usuario" que provém de um arquivo texto, ele funciona como um layout para a importação desses registros, usei ponto e vírgula para delimitar a posição desses dados no arquivo, fazendo com que seja inserido no banco de dados o `numero` e a `situacao` de cada usuário. 
Queria adicionar um campo `status` também lá no BD, mas a dúvida está na hora de montar o insert pois pra cada tipo de situação é atribuído um valor diferente:

status=1 para ativo e status=2 para inativo.

Eu teria que comparar a posição `situacao` de cada linha antes de inserir no BD, se é a situação é "ATIVO" atribui status=1 se for "INATIVO" atribui status=2

Ex:

**arquivo.txt (Layout)**

```
NUMERO | SITUAÇÃO  
1      | ATIVO  
2      | INATIVO
```

Após o `insert` deveria ficar assim no BD:

**tb_usuario**

```
ID  | NUMERO | SITUACAO | STATUS  
1     1        ATIVO       1         
2     2        INATIVO     2
```

**importador.php**

```
function Inserir($itens, Pdo $pdo){
   $sts = $pdo->prepare("
        INSERT  INTO tb_usuario(numero,situacao) 
        VALUES(?,?);
        ");
    $sts->bindValue(1, $itens[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(2, $itens[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->execute();
    $sts->closeCursor();
    $sts = NULL;

}
if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
    $Pdo     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste", "root", "");
    $file    = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    while (!feof($file)){
        $linha = fgets($file);          
        $itens = explode(';', $linha);          
        Inserir($itens, $Pdo);
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Importar Arquivo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que seu arquivo txt seja algo assim:

```
1      ; ATIVO  
2      ; INATIVO
3      ; INATIVO
4      ; INATIVO 
5      ; ATIVO
```

Se eu entendi corretamente a pergunta, seu código PHP ficará desta maneira:

```
<?php function Inserir($itens, Pdo $pdo){
    if($itens[1] == 'INATIVO')
    {
        $status = 2;
    }
    else {
        $status = 1;
    }
   $sts = $pdo->prepare("
        INSERT  INTO tb_usuario(numero,situacao, status) 
        VALUES(?,?,?);
        ");
    $sts->bindValue(1, $itens[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(2, $itens[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(3, $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sts->execute();
    $sts->closeCursor();
    $sts = NULL;

}
if (!empty($_FILES['arquivo']))
{
    $Pdo     = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste", "root", "");
    $file    = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    while (!feof($file)){
        $linha = fgets($file);          
        $itens = explode(';', $linha); 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($itens); $i++)
        {
            $itens[$i] = trim($itens[$i]);
        }
        Inserir($itens, $Pdo);
    }
}

?>
```

Neste caso eu considerei que a coluna "situação" sempre será a segunda coluna.

Acho também importante ressaltar que é importante verificar se o arquivo é realmente de extensão .txt se você pretende que outros usuário utilizem esta aplicação.

Comment: Muito obrigado Christian, era isso mesmo!